# MSTest with C++: Test Methods are not runnable

Tags: c++, c++-cli, mstest

I try to use MSTest so as to perform unit tests on native C++ code (so as to try to implement Test Driven Development).

There's an MSTest entry in the "Add New Project" C++ Wizard. It creates some code obviously in C+++/CLI.

However, whenever I try to run these tests, Visual Studio indicates me that the tests are not runnable:

```
Not Runnable    TestMethod2 CargoOCRTests   UTA007: Method TestMethod2 defined in class CargoOCRTests.UnitTest1 does not have correct signature. Test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute must be non-static, public, does not return a value and should not take any parameter. for example: public void Test.Class1.Test().
```

However I think my two tests functions do respect the prototype VS is complaining about:

```
namespace CargoOCRTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert::IsTrue(true);
        };

        [TestMethod]
        void TestMethod2()
        {
            Assert::IsTrue(false);
        };
    };
}
```

Have you any idea what is the cause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your test methods as `public`

```
public:
   [TestMethod]
   void TestMethod1() {}
```